# Are styles included in a stylesheet using add_editor_style loaded in the front end?

Tags: add-editor-style

I am writing a stylesheet that will help show the content in the TinyMCE editor look more like it would appear on the front end of the website using the add_editor_style function in the WordPress theme functions file. I may even end up adding a few style rules in the editor-style.css file just to be used on content.

So I am wondering if the styles added to the editor-style.css stylesheet are also loaded on the front of the website when the page gets rendered? I checked the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) and I didn't see anything that specifically stated one way or the other.

```
add_editor_style( "editor-style.css" );
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual code from the themes functions file:

```
function custom_theme_features()  {
    add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_features' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the full code to include the editor style in a common way.

```
<?php
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
?>
```

When you are adding the custom editor style, you need to use `admin_init` hook which is triggered only when you are inside the admin panel. So the stylesheet will not load in the front end and is limited to admin dashboard.

Comment: What if after_setup_theme is used in the add_action hook instead of admin_init? Will the editor styles be loaded on the front end then while still being loaded in the editor? I updated my question to show what I presently have in my theme.

Comment: I believe that styles added with `add_editor_style` do not appear in the front-end regardless of where they are loaded.That said, you should use the `admin_init` action hook since it will be more efficient and only run in the admin area =)

Comment: I just checked the code using `after_setup_theme`, it doesn't load in front end either. So we can be assured `add_editor_style` doesn't append style to front end.

Comment: Thank you for following up. That is what I needed to know.